# How do you make Tan[A+B] expansion give the well known high school answer?

Tags: trigonometry

What command makes `Tan[A+B]` expand to `(Tan[A]+Tan[B])/(1-Tan[A]Tan[B])`? `TrigExpand` does not give it directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest way is the following:

```
tansum = Tan[a_ + b_] :> (Tan[a] + Tan[b])/(1 - Tan[a] Tan[b]);
```

Then we run

```
Tan[A + B] /. tansum
```

> `(Tan[A] + Tan[B])/(1 - Tan[A] Tan[B])`

Likewise for other trigonometric identities

Edit: after the comment for generalization for $n$-angles.

If we try to do it like this for the case $n=3$ it seems to be working

```
Tan[a1 + a2 + a3] /. tansum /. tansum // Factor
```

> `(-Tan[a1] - Tan[a2] - Tan[a3] + Tan[a1] Tan[a2] Tan[a3])/(-1 +  Tan[a1] Tan[a2] + Tan[a1] Tan[a3] + Tan[a2] Tan[a3])`

Comment: Thanks. This is close to what I want. Can we write a code to express Tan[a1+a2+...+an] purely in terms of Tan[a1], Tan[a2], Tan[a3], ....

Comment: @QuasarSupernova I don't know the formula in terms of sums of `Tan[a1]`,...,`Tan[an]` by heart. If you can post it, I am happy to give it a go. Otherwise I will try it tomorrow, as it's pretty late here

Comment: @QuasarSupernova please see the edit I added to the answer, and let me know. If I remember there's a general formula in terms of sums of products in the numerator and denominator, but I am not quite sure what you are after :-)

Comment: @kcr you can also use  //. tansum instead of  /. tansum /.tansum

Answer (score 8):

It is in the Wolfram Knowledgebase

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Tan"]["AdditionFormulas"][[1]][
  A, B] // Activate

(* Tan[A + B] == (Tan[A] + Tan[B])/(1 - Tan[A] Tan[B]) *)
```

Verifying,

```
% // Simplify

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** Converting the equality into a rule

```
rule = Tan[A_ + B_] :> Evaluate[%%[[-1]]]

(* Tan[A_ + B_] :> (Tan[A] + Tan[B])/(1 - Tan[A] Tan[B]) *)
```

Handling multiple addends in argument to `Tan`,

```
Simplify[Tan[a + b + c + d] //. rule, ExcludedForms -> _Tan]

(* (Tan[b] + Tan[c] + Tan[d] - Tan[b] Tan[c] Tan[d] - 
   Tan[a] (-1 + Tan[c] Tan[d] + Tan[b] (Tan[c] + Tan[d])))/(1 - 
   Tan[c] Tan[d] - Tan[b] (Tan[c] + Tan[d]) + 
   Tan[a] (-Tan[c] - Tan[d] + Tan[b] (-1 + Tan[c] Tan[d]))) *)
```

Verifying,

```
% // Simplify

(* Tan[a + b + c + d] *)
```

Comment: I want to be able to finally Expand Tan[a1 + a2 + ..... + an ] only in terms of Tan[a1], Tan[a2], ... for a variable "n"

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, An extension of Tan[a+b] is interesting, but explain how you arrive at those steps.?

Comment: @janhardo - [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) with the rule transforms the original expression into one with only  `Tan` of atomic arguments; however, it needs to be simplified. Simple application of [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) would just return the original expression. Consequently, the option [`ExcludedForms`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExcludedForms.html) is used to prevent the `Tan` terms from being recombined.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon thanks,This is not immediately so easy to fathom, although some of the terms are familiar.

Answer (score 5):

You can do a step-by-step derivation, suppressing the evaluation using a change of case.

```
expr0 = Tan[a + b]
```

$$\tan (a+b)$$

`expr1 = TrigExpand[expr0] /. {Cos -> cos, Sin -> sin}`

$$\frac{\sin (a) \cos (b)}{\cos (a) \cos (b)-\sin (a) \sin (b)}+\frac{\cos (a) \sin (b)}{\cos (a) \cos (b)-\sin (a) \sin (b)}$$

```
expr2 = expr1 /. {sin[a_] -> tan[a] cos[a] }
```

$$\frac{\cos (a) \tan (a) \cos (b)}{\cos (a) \cos (b)-\cos (a) \tan (a) \cos (b) \tan (b)}+\frac{\cos (a) \cos (b) \tan (b)}{\cos (a) \cos (b)-\cos (a) \tan (a) \cos (b) \tan (b)}$$

```
expr3 = Factor[expr2] /. tan -> Tan
```

$$-\frac{\tan (a)+\tan (b)}{\tan (a) \tan (b)-1}$$

```
expr3 // Simplify
```

> Tan[a+b]

---

The same procedure for `Tan[a+b+c+d]` results in:

$$-\frac{\tan (a) \tan (b) \tan (c)+\tan (a) \tan (b) \tan (d)+\tan (a) \tan (c) \tan (d)-\tan (a)+\tan (b) \tan (c) \tan (d)-\tan (b)-\tan (c)-\tan (d)}{\tan (a) \tan (b) \tan (c) \tan (d)-\tan (a) \tan (b)-\tan (a) \tan (c)-\tan (a) \tan (d)-\tan (b) \tan (c)-\tan (b) \tan (d)-\tan (c) \tan (d)+1}$$

Answer (score 4):

If the question concerns the derivation, not the application,  of the "high school formula" one can derive it , similar to @Syed's answer, in a direct way :

```
((Tan[a + b] // TrigExpand) /. {a ->  ArcTan[ua], b ->  ArcTan[ub]} //TrigExpand // Simplify) /. {ua -> Tan[a ], ub -> Tan[b ]}
(*(Tan[a] + Tan[b])/(1 - Tan[a] Tan[b])*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Lots of good answers, but here's a trick I think is worth knowing

```
TrigExpand[Tan[x + y]] /. Sin[u_] -> Cos[u] HoldForm[Tan[u]] //
   Simplify // ReleaseHold
(* (Tan[x] + Tan[y])/(1 - Tan[x] Tan[y]) *)
```

This works by making the (obviously valid) replacement

```
Sin[u_] -> Cos[u] Tan[u]
```

In itself, this would achieve little as (I guess) that Mathematica would simplify the result back to the unwanted form.  However, wrapping `HoldForm` round the tangents means that Mathematica will not change them.  Consequently, the simplest form is the one that we seek.

`ReleaseHold` removes the `HoldForm` wrapper.  In this case, this doesn't change the appearance of the result, but means that the `Tan` terms will behave as expected in subsequent processing.

Comment: Its a good trick , can you explain how this trick works?